# Sample testcase for Interviewstreet: Equations

Tags: c++, math, testcase, equations

So there is a website named interviewstreet.com. Here we can find challenging programming problems. Unfortunately you have to be logged in to see the questions.

Here's a brief description of the problem I'm attempting to solve:

> Find the no of positive integral solutions for the equations `(1/x) + (1/y) = 1/N!` (read 1 by n factorial) Print a single integer which is the no of positive integral solutions modulo 1000007.

For example, when `N=3`, `(x,y)` can be: `(7,42)`, `(9,18)`, `(8,24)`, `(12,12)`, `(42,7)`, `(18,9)`, `(24,8)`. Or so I thought.

Help me please, especially you who have solved this problem. I have just coded for the problem Equations. There is something wrong with my algorithm, can I ask for output for the first 10 integers? i.e. `N=2`, `N=3`, `N=4` ... `N=10` so that I can find out the flaw in my algorithm. Thanks :)

EDIT: Oh, please don't post solution code as it will ruin the fun for me and for people trying to solve this :)

Comment: If you've already coded up a solution, please post the code.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't think it will be nice to post solutions. I just need the output of those testcases I put, for me to evaluate my algorithm

Comment: To clarify, I asked that *you* post your solution if you want us to check over your algorithm. I wasn't suggesting that someone here post a solution to solve the problem for you.

Comment: But then I will spoil it for others. Actually I was asking for "what your program outputs when given the above inputs", not for my code to be checked. Nevermind, I have solved it finally. Thanks for your help :) In case anyone stumbled upon this problem, here is the output of sample testcases I asked for:
N=1, ans=1;
N=2, ans=3;
N=3, ans=9;
N=4, ans=21;
N=5, ans=63;
N=6, ans=135;
N=7, ans=405;
N=8, ans=675;
N=9, ans=1215;
N=10, ans=2295;

Comment: You missed (10,15)  and (15,10).

Comment: I got my code figuring out the answers for small N but it isn't ideal for large values of N. Any hints on how to solve for large values of N (the second test case is 32327 which gets too large for a Java long when figuring it's factorial value). I can use a BigInteger but I don't think that's the correct approach. Just a quick please, no solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My solutions was accepted by interview street. 
Firstly, my solutions wasn't accepted, but after saw @Reinardus Surya Pradhit post, i realized, if pair (x, y) will be count twice, so i change it a litter bit and got success
I will not post my solution here, but i can tell you the test case for all variable from N = 3 -> N = 10
Here the result

```
N=3: 9
N=4: 21
N=5: 63 
N=6: 135
N=7: 405
N=8: 675
N=9: 1215
N=10: 2295
```

My hint is: try to express N! in primes from like `p1^q1 * p2^q2 * ... * pn^qn`

Comment: what is the output for N=131399, I am getting 598995, but it's giving wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Disregarding the special form of `N!` for the moment, to solve the equation

```
1/k = 1/x + 1/y
```

write `x = k + d`. Then

```
1/y = 1/k - 1/(k + d) = d/(k*(k+d))
```

The task of determining the number of solutions from that is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Thanks for your answer sir. Actually I already have my own idea. Can you give me the output for N=1 ~ N=10 sir? I need them to find out the flaw of my algorithm. Thanks :)

Comment: The numbers you posted are correct, you seem to have found the flaw. Congrats.

Answer (score 0):

It is important to only deal with integers to avoid rounding errors: start by rearranging the equation to:

```
N!(X+Y)=XY
```

I'm not sure where to go from there.

Answer (score 0):

to arrive at final result we need to calculate (2*q1+1)*(2*q2+1)*(2*q3+1)... 
But how we will store the result , let say N=32327 which will overflow above result.
Please correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: Did you calculate modulo by 1000007 for the result?